# Кнопка с onClick работает только один раз на react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Я делаю сайт на реакте, хотел сделать раскрывающееся меня. Я сделал кнопку, которая при нажатии на нее должна менять bool переменную на противоположное значение, но кнопка работает только один раз, то есть меняет значение с false на true, а обратно нет (кнопка становиться неактивной, курсор не подсвечивает ее как ссылку, при нажатии нет никакого ответа, меню остается открытым).
Код класса (урезан):

```
 class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {isOpened: false};
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({isOpened: !this.state.isOpened});
  };

  render() {
    const path = history.location && history.location.pathname;
    return (
      <div className={s['header-left']}>
        <div className={s.logo}>
          <a href="/">
            <img
              width="160"
              height="85.75"
              src={logo}
              alt="Halm Personalberatung Köln"
            />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className={s.button}>
          <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
          </a>
        </div>
```

Код меню (в этом же классе):

```
<Collapse isOpened={this.state}>
        <nav className={`${s.menu} ${s.mobile}`}>
          ...
        </nav>
      </Collapse>
```

Answer (score 1):

А если так?

```
<Collapse isOpened={this.state.isOpened}>
```

Comment: Верно + ответ можно найти тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465983/button-with-onclick-only-works-once-in-react/53466739#53466739